# Put PHP code in existing PHP code

Tags: php, wordpress

Here is the code:

```
<?php if(function_exists('mk_slider')){mk_slider(427);} ?>
```

I need to put code

```
<?php the_field('slider_id'); ?>
```

instead of 427 in previous code, but it does not work, how shell i do it?

Help plz!

Comment: Try `mk_slider(get_field('slider_id'))`

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
<?php if(function_exists('mk_slider')){mk_slider(get_field('slider_id'));} ?>
                                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

... and as a side note, now I need a shower. Dealing with wordpress code always leaves me feeling dirty/abused.

Comment: are you sure its not `get_field`?